# Displaying moving pieces in my chess game lags, what can I do about it?

Tags: c#, optimization, lag, chess

First time I ever ask a question here so correct me if I´m doing it wrong.

Picture of my chess set:
[image]

Every time I move a piece it lags for about 1 second. Every piece and tile has an Image and there is exactly 96 Images. Every time I move a piece it clears everything with black and then update the graphics.

In the early stages of the chess I didn't have any Images and used different colors instead and only a few pieces there was no noticeable lag and the piece moved in an instant.

```
        public void updateGraphics(PaintEventArgs e, Graphics g, Bitmap frame)
    {
        g = Graphics.FromImage(frame);
        g.Clear(Color.Black);


        colorMap(g);

        g.Dispose();
        e.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(frame, 0, 0);
    }
```

The function colorMap(g) looks like this:

```
        private void colorMap(Graphics g)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < SomeInts.amount; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < SomeInts.amount; x++)
            {
                //Tiles
                Bundle.tile[x, y].colorBody(g, x, y);

                //Pieces
                player1.colorAll(g);
                player2.colorAll(g);
            }
        }
    }
```

The colorAll function executes every pieces colorBody(g) function which look like this:

```
        public void colorBody(Graphics g)
    {
        //base.colorBody() does the following: body = new Rectangle(x * SomeInts.size + SomeInts.size / 4, y * SomeInts.size + SomeInts.size / 4, size, size);
        base.colorBody();

        if (team == 1)
        {
            //If its a white queen
            image = Image.FromFile("textures/piece/white/queen.png");
        }
        if (team == 2)
        {
            //If its a black queen
            image = Image.FromFile("textures/piece/black/queen.png");
        }
        g.DrawImage(image, body);
    }
```

and finaly the function that moves the piece:

```
        public void movePiece(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < SomeInts.amount; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < SomeInts.amount; x++)
            {
                if (Bundle.tile[x, y].body.Contains(e.Location))
                {
                    //Ignore this
                    for (int i = 0; i < queens.Count; i++)
                    {
                        Queen temp = queens.ElementAt<Queen>(i);
                        temp.move(x, y);
                    }
                    //Relevant
                    player1.move(x, y);
                    player2.move(x, y);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Thank you for reading all this! I could make a link to the whole program if my coding examples is not enough.

Comment: How large are your images?  I'm going to guess they're quite large.

Comment: `Image.FromFile()` - are you re-loading the images for every square for every frame? Can you load all the images once and just re-use those copies? (That said, re-loading them all ought to be fairly cheap too.) And is this in the OnPaint()? Are you redrawing everything or just what's changed / what you've been asked to redraw? And how exactly are you colouring the squares beneath the pieces - is that efficient?

Comment: A good old double buffering technique will help you a lot (http://www.developerfusion.com/code/4668/double-buffering-in-net/), plus the @rup suggestion to avoid calling FromFile each time.

Comment: Tip for next time: use a profiler, you would immediately see you spend hugh amounts of time loading images from disc over and over again.

Comment: I went here expecting to link you to several bithacks on chessprogramming.wikispaces.com .. but you have trouble with the *drawing*? Maybe don't load your pictures every time.

Comment: If you used a profiler such as [dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) it would have caught that immediately.

Comment: A lot of good stuff here. I will begin with trying the Image array thing. Thanks.

Comment: It runs smooth now. The player class which creates its pieces now dictates which picture a piece shall have in the constructor like this: knight1 = new Knight(0, 0, name, image[2]);

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're calling `Image.FromFile` in every refresh, for every image - effectively reloading every image file every time from disk.

Have you considered loading the images *once*, and storing the resulting `Image`s somewhere useful? (say, an array, `Image[2,6]` would be adequate)

Comment: Well seen. This makes zero sense and seriously creates lag.

Comment: I never though of that. Thank you I will try that out!

Answer (score 3):

Why do you redraw the board each time? Can't you just leave the board where it is and display an image with transparent background over it? That way you have one image as a background (the board), plus 64 smaller images placed over the board in a grid and just change the image being displayed on each move.

That way, you can let windows handle the drawing...

Also, load the images of the pieces at the start of the application.

Comment: Sounds really interesting. Could you give an example?

Comment: well... an image control for the board. Then, 8x8 smaller image controls placed (with a grid layout manager) over the board. The images controls can be bound to the image at runtime depending on the chess pieces...

Answer (score 1):

In addition to not calling `Image.FromFile()` inside `updateGraphics()` *(which is definitely your biggest issue)*, you shouldn't be attempting to redraw the entire board every on every call to `updateGraphics()` - most of the time, only a small portion of the board will be invalidated.

The `PaintEventArgs` contains an parameter, `ClipRectangle`, which specifies which portion of the board needs redrawing.  See if you can't figure out which tiles intersect with that rectangle, and only redraw those tiles :)

*Hint: Write a function `Point ScreenToTileCoords(Point)` which takes a screen coordinate and returns which board-tile is at that coordinate.  Then the only tiles you need to redraw are*

```
Point upperLeftTileToBeDrawn = ScreenToTileCoords(e.ClipRectangle.Left, e.ClipRectangle.Top);
Point lowerRightTileToBeDrawn = ScreenToTileCoords(e.ClipRectangle.Right - 1, e.ClipRectangle.Bottom- 1);
```

---

Also, make sure your control is double-buffered, to avoid tearing.  This is much simpler than @Steve B's link in the comments above states; assuming this is a `UserControl`, simply set

```
this.DoubleBuffered = true;
```

Comment: Duoble buffered in form1 is checked. I will look into that clipRectangle thing.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what about this:

Do not clear the whole board but only those parts that need to be cleared.

Alternative:

Update to WPF - it moves drawing to the graphics card - and just move pieces around, in a smart way (i.e. have a control / object for every piece).

Comment: I was thinking about that put did not come up with a good way of doing that. Could you please give me a code sample of that?